# How can I save multiple value in v-model on vue.js 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

My vue component like this :

```
<template>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <a @click="deleteAll" href="javascript:" class="btn btn-danger pull-right">
            <span class="fa fa-trash"></span> Delete All
        </a>    
        ...
            <tr v-for="item in list">
                <td>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" :value="item.id" v-model="checkedData">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                ...
            </tr>
        ...
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                checkedData: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            deleteAll() {
                this.$http.post(window.BaseUrl+'/message/deleteAll', {ids: this.checkedData})
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

If I check the some checkbox and click delete all button, it will send value `item.id` by ajax

I want to send another value too. I have value `item.seller_id` and `item.buyer_id`

I try like this :

```
<input type="checkbox" :value="item._id+'#'+item.seller_id+'#'+item.buyer_id" v-model="checkedData">
```

So I use separator `#` to separate the value. Seems it works

Whether it is the best solution? Or is there another better solution?

Comment: does this actually work? I would expect that `<input type="checkbox" :value="item.id" v-model="checkedData">` inside an iterator would not work, as your're using the same (array) model for all items. Anyway, if you can clean up your model so that it holds the data needed, passing it using a post ajax call is straight forward. Of course this may depend on your back-end too

Answer (score 0):

Hi please look at this https://jsfiddle.net/p8zhrg6g/29/ .

```
<div v-for="item in list">
    <input type="checkbox" :id="item.id" :value="item.value" v-model="checkedNames">
    <label :for="item.id">{{item.value}}</label>
```

This is how I would have done it, hope this helps?

Answer (score 0):

Just put value in array in :value..

```
<div v-for="item in list">
    <input type="checkbox" :id="item.id" :value="[item.name, item.value]" v-model="checkedNames">
    <label :for="item.id">{{item.value}}</label>
```

When you want call the value in another element, you can call value based on their value index like {{item[0]}} will display item.name and {{item[1]}} will display value.value